# Draw Rotated (Vertical) Barcode Using QPL (Quick PDF LIbrary)

Tags: c#, pdf, barcode

I need to draw rotated (vertical) barcode using qpl. I can draw horizontal (green marked) barcode, but can't find any way to draw vertical/rotated (red marked) barcode.

**Note: this is sample/original pdf, i need to print similar barcode in output file**

[image]

i have tried to roated the page, then draw the barcode.. but it doesn't works.. here is how it looks like:

[image]

any idea how to draw rotated barcode using qpl?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Quick PDF Library, but rather than rotating the page, have your tried rotating the barcode image?

Comment: The rotated barcodes look great, they are just missing the text.  The text is captions. So you need to get the captions from original bar code and then add to rotated bar code.

Comment: @user09938, sir, that library does not produce barcode as image, it's just draw it on the pdf, could be vector or something like that?

Comment: @jdweng, sir, may be you are looking at 1st image, that's the source/original pdf file, i need to replicate the barcode in new document.. please check the 2nd image.

Comment: It seems to be a paid product. You may consider contacting them to explain your needs. If a rotated barcode is not currently supported, they may consider adding support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After posting same question to that library (qpl) forum, i got my answer.

I have overlooked the documentation where it says.. how to pass the barcode text. As i thought it will be a separate method to rotate the barcode.

Basically i just need to append specific keywords with the barcode text to make the code draw rotated. here what's needed to add to barcode text:

```
/RC = Rotate clockwise
/RA = Rotate anti-clockwise
/RU = Rotate 180 degrees
```

source:

[Barcode Documentation](https://www.debenu.com/docs/pdf_library_reference/DrawBarcode.php)

best regards

Comment: Since you didn't include any code in the OP, you may consider adding a small example that shows how to create the barcode in your OP using the information that you discovered.